# Render image on React web app

Tags: image, reactjs, upload

I have a form like that:

```
<InsertItemComponent
                    name={"MAIN IMAGE"}
                    cName={"input-file"}
                    req={true}
                    tType={"file"}
                    onChange={this.handleProductMainImage}
                    accept={".jpg, .jpeg, .png"}
                />
```

InsertItemComponent:

```
<div className="form-group">
            <label className="col-md-4 control-label">{this.props.name}</label>
            <div className="col-md-4">
                <input name={this.props.forName} placeholder={this.props.name} onChange={this.props.onChange}
                    className={this.props.cName} required={this.props.req} type={this.props.tType}
                    accept={this.props.accept} />
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now i have my handler that successfully extract the image object:

```
handleProductMainImage = e => {
    console.log(e.target.files[0]);
}
```

My question is how could i render this to show the image which i selected.
And how i could encoded/decoded that image on string so i can send as a string type on server

Comment: I tried but is an object

Comment: Ideally you send stringified file object to server . I am not sure may be if you will add  small meaningful snippet of code , it will help to understand

Answer (score 0):

Make use of React state. use setState() to reflect the new image selected